# How to implement Memcache in Drupal 8?

Tags: memcached, drupal-8

I read a few very good online resources that describe how exactly we can implement Memcache in Drupal 8. for e.g. this one

https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/configuring-memcache-drupal-8-to-reduce-database-load

At the Drupal end I have installed two new modules for Memcache:

1. Memcached
2. Memcached Storage

But, when trying to enable them it throws an error "PHP extension is required".

Also, getting this error "*Unable to initialize module*" when trying to install PHP extension using below command:

> sudo apt install php-memcached

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

#### Add Memcache in Drupal-8

1. Added two new modules and installed them in Drupal.

   - Memcache
   - Memcache Admin

2. Install below packages in existing Drupal Dockerfile.

   - libmemcached-dev
   - memcached
   - Docker-php-ext-enable memcached
3. Finally, update settings.php with memcache configs (***../web/sites/default/settings.php***)

> $settings['memcache']['servers'] = ['127.0.0.1:11211' => 'default'];
>   $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';
>   $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] =
>   'cache.backend.memcache';
>   $settings['memcache_storage']['debug'] = TRUE;

**Note:** We can view Memcache statistic via https://localhost/admin/reports/memcache

[image]

Memcache is installed successfully!